# Is there a way to use Dataframe's isin() without using a list?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Is there a way to use Dataframe's isin() without using a list?

I'm looking at the [pyspark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isin) and it looks like it takes either a string or a list. What if the string or a list is absolutely massive? Is there an alternative?

Comment: .... what sort of alternative are you looking for, exactly?

Comment: You can try a Join.

Comment: you can do a left-semi join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either subquery

```
spark.createDataFrame([(1, ), (2, ), (3, ), (4, )], ["x"]).createTempView("df1")
spark.createDataFrame([(1, ), (3, ) ], ["x"]).createTempView("df2")

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM df1 WHERE x IN (SELECT x FROM df2)").show()
+---+                                                                           
|  x|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
+---+
```

or join (for example `semi` [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895143/is-there-a-way-to-use-dataframes-isin-without-using-a-list/47895368#comment82757287_47895143) by [Raphael Roth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138523/raphael-roth)):

```
spark.table("df1").join(spark.table("df2"), ["x"], "leftsemi").show()
+---+                                                                           
|  x|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
+---+
```

Comment: This solves the problem. I wish we could just use the function instead of having to do all of these mental Olympics.